# using Swift 2.2 Pods with XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I installed the new XCode 8 and trying to run my project. Some of the Pods i use were not update yet to Swift 2.3/3.0 and the project won't compile. How can i use older Pods in my project?

Comment: You can't. But many pods have swift3-branches, which you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check procedures [here](http://radex.io/xcode7-xcode8/) that will make your `swift 2.2` or `swift 2.3` pods compatible with Xcode8 as its.

As steps:

1. To begin, open your project in Xcode 7. Go to project settings, open the Build settings tab, and click the “+” to add a User-Defined Setting: `SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3`
   [image]
2. In your Podfile you should put the following post install script. Don't forget to replace YOURTEAMID with your own

> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
>     # Configure Pod targets for Xcode 8 compatibility
>     config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
>     config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = 'YOURTEAMID/'
>     config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
>   end
> en
> ```

Keep in mind that will work fine with most Pods, but not all I still struggling with `Eureka` pod to work.